# Return singleton instances of descendants

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, singleton

I have a couple of classes that are singletons so I tried to create a parent BaseClass with method GetInstance(params) and derived classes, that should implement this method and return instances of theiselfs (so I dont have to cast them)... as they are singletons the method should be static, but its not allowed to override static methods. What would be the best approach to code it? sample code what i wanted:

```
  public class Base {

    public static virtual T GetInstance<T>() where T : class;
  }


  public class Derived {
    Derived instance;

    public static override T GetInstance<T>() where T : typeOf(this){
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Derived();
        }
      return instance;
    }
  }
```

in the code outside of this i want to call

```
Derived.GetInstance().SomeDerivedMethod()
```

not

```
(Derived.GetInstance() as Derived).SomeDerivedMethod() and not
new Derived().getInstance().SomeDerivedMethod()
```

I know this is not good, and i have lack of experience with the T type too, so any advices are welcomed.
thanks

**EDIT:**

Or if it is possible somehow define the GetInstance() method in Base, so the derived class does not need to ovwerride it, but it will return the instance of class from where it was called... Derived.GetInstance() will return instance of Derived

Comment: What purpose should this class have? It is likely that an IoC container would be more appropriate.

Comment: I will have more singletons, therefore i wanted to pull up the logic for creating instances in way that a static inherited method from parent could always return a instance of type from where it was called (even if it is from descendant)

Comment: here is similar discussion http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=376943 and it looks like there is no way to force the descendant to be singletons, looks like i wanted something weird.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary<Type, Object>` for your singletones. The method below requires each type to implement the constructor private. Of course you could also make a check in each of the derived classes if there is already a instance of the class in the singletones dictionary. This would even avoid somebody to use the `Activator` to create a instance.

**Not tested:**

```
public class Base {
    static Dictionary<Type, Object> _Singletones = new Dictionary<Type, Object>();
    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (_Singletones.ContainsKey(t))
             return _Singletones[t] as T;
        else {
            // Create instance by calling private constructor and return it
            T result = Activator.CreateInstance(t, true) as T;
            _Singletones.Add(t, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ok, although a static method like this should be made thread safe.

Comment: yes man! its almost it... but how could I get the type not from the parameter but from the calling class so instead of Base.GetInstance<Derived>() = Derived.GetInstance<Derived>() i should call Base.GetInstance() which returns Base and Derived.get.. which returns Derived

Comment: @Groo You are right, but this could nasty when you have performance critical code( e.g. when accessing the method many times ). Maybe working with 2 dictionaries( Swapping ) would improve performance then.

Comment: @Zavael I don't think this is possible. You need to access it with `Base.GetInstance<Dervied>()`. ( Without base when working in a dervied class )

Comment: @Felix: not sure what you mean by swapping. If it needs to be accessed from different threads, it should be thread safe, unless all possible values are instantiated at startup and the dictionary is used as readonly (and nothing enforces that right now).

Comment: @Zavael: then your method shouldn't be static. Use a base generic class with an instance method which uses a static dictionary. But most likely, you are doing something wrong if you need this.

Comment: I will have more singletons, therefore i wanted to pull up the logic for creating instances in way that a static inherited method from parent could always return a instance of type from where it was called (even if it is from descendant) but it looks like i will use some factory pattern, thanks for comments

Comment: thanks i used this with a small change... public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : Base { ... than it is obviou that it will be Base descendants :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the Abstract Factory design pattern. Maybe other [creational design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) may fit too.

You need to enforce the "singleton-ness" on factory level, and then the call may look like:

```
FooFactory.GetBarInstance().SomeDerivedMethod();
```

Comment: @Zavael: that's why it's called abstract. If you need a Foo, you use a FooFactory. It can implement a generic interface, but each factory instantiates its own type.

Answer (score 2):

its not an real answer but maybe its nice to know anyway. [Lazy](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx)

Comment: +1 thanks for the lazysingleton1 double check :) the lambda version i could not use as i have not one instance, but a dictionary of singletons

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply declare the method as non-generic and use the derived type directly:

```
public class Derived {
  Derived instance;

  public static Derived GetInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Derived();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it is a way. i wanted to force any derived class to implement the singleton method GetInstance() through the parent Base..

Comment: You cannot force implementation of a static method in C#

Comment: yes i know, thats why i asked for advices, if it is possible at all to achieve what i want :)

Comment: @Zavael - it depends. It is not possible with the textbook implementation of singleton using a static method. But a much better way to enforce singleton-ness is to use IoC and let the container manage the lifetime of your instances. It should be trivial in most frameworks to declare that all subclasses of a given class have singleton lifetime.