# Enforce Singleton in Class Hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

Is there a way to enforce singleton in a class hierarchy ? I don't have a use case for this, I am just curious if it's possible ?

Hierarchy in the sense, all class'es inheriting from this class would also be singletons.

Comment: Singletons are evil. Kill them with fire!! Don't invent new ways to use them.

Comment: Enforce them is inpossible afaik. But if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971644/return-singleton-instances-of-descendants/8972498#8972498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You can help them be a Singleton but you can't enforce the access control of their constructors, so it's impossible to *force* them to be Singletons.